# How to train Yolo model with GPU of 'NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050 Laptop GPU

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, object-detection, yolov5, yolov8

I'm newbie to object detection model, I'm trying to train yolo model in my device('NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050 Laptop GPU), I am getting errors,
I have image size of (1365, 1024, 3) , I tried with image size(1365, 1024, 3) then my system struck. then I change with size into (1020, 640) , after the error like Yolo training recommended with 2 GPUs  was it my system for training yolo. please help me with that.
this is my code.

## Load a model

```
from ultralytics import YOLO

model = YOLO('yolov8n.pt')  # load a pretrained model (recommended for training)
model.train(data='datasets/m_train.yaml', 
                epochs=8, 
                imgsz=(1020, 640), 
                batch = 12,
                optimizer = 'Adam',
                device=[0,1]
                )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ultralytics` already uses `Dataloader()`
behind the scenes so there is no need for a custom implementation (I don't even know if you really need it, for other custom implementation/logic you would implement specific callbacks for customization).

The truth is that you have quite big image sizes in conjunction with big batch sizes, 3050Ti has only 4 GB of VRAM memory, so you are very likely to easily run into OOM issues.

You could try to start with `(600x600)` and a batch_size of `2` and then gradually increase the batch_size to `(3,4 etc.)`

Comment: Thanks @Timbus Calin.. It was working.

Answer (score 0):

Using a dataloader can solve the problem as you're passing the data on a whole that your GPU can't process. this is known as loading the data in a single batch, which can be memory intensive for large datasets. So what the data loader does is it loads the data in batches by sampling them at random. Shuffling the data at random helps in reducing the bias.

```
training_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(<your_dataset>, batch_size=3, shuffle=True)
```

From the official documentation of pytorch refer : [https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/introyt/trainingyt.html#:~:text=The%20DataLoader%20pulls%20instances%20of%20data%20from%20the,regardless%20of%20the%20type%20of%20data%20they%20contain](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/introyt/trainingyt.html#:%7E:text=The%20DataLoader%20pulls%20instances%20of%20data%20from%20the,regardless%20of%20the%20type%20of%20data%20they%20contain).

Another suggestion could be scaling the image size further for faster training.

Hope it helps as I too once ran into memory allocation errors.....